# UISegmentControl Programmatically segments frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm using a segment control in the following manner.

```
    CGFloat segmentWidth = 70;
    CGFloat segmentHeight = 40;
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (HCIPGRentDetail *object in self.pgHouse.rents) {
        [arr addObject:object.roomTypeId];
    }
    UISegmentedControl *sharingSegmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:arr];
    [sharingSegmentControl setApportionsSegmentWidthsByContent:YES];
    sharingSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.pgHouse.rents.count * segmentWidth, segmentHeight);
    for (int i = 0; i < sharingSegmentControl.numberOfSegments; i++) {
        [sharingSegmentControl setWidth:segmentWidth forSegmentAtIndex:i];
        [sharingSegmentControl setTitle:arr[i] forSegmentAtIndex:i];
    }
    sharingSegmentControl.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, currentHeight + sharingSegmentControl.frame.size.height/2);
    currentHeight += sharingSegmentControl.frame.size.height;
    [sharingSegmentControl.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
    [sharingSegmentControl.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [sharingSegmentControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
    [sharingSegmentControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [sharingSegmentControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    [self.mainScrollView addSubview:sharingSegmentControl];
```

It just displays the segment control with blue colour background and red colour, the segments get a frame (debugger) like {{0,0},{0,29}}. Doesn't understand what I'm missing.

The debugger says this

```
<__NSArrayM 0x1411be30>(
<UISegment: 0x1411bd60; frame = (0 0; 0 29); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1411bd30>>,
<UISegment: 0x1411a1c0; frame = (0 0; 0 29); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1411b220>>
)
```

Comment: is your object contains value ?

Comment: Yes it has. The titles are set properly too.

Comment: the problem is with the center, which you are setting after assigning a frame. 'The center is specified within the coordinate system of its superview and is measured in points. Setting this property changes the values of the frame properties accordingly' [Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

Comment: @pawan Doesn't really explain why the width of the segment (all segments) is set to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that tint colour was the problem. Maybe segment control take the tint colour default as clear colour or so.

Somehow, when I just set the tint colour. I got the frame correct, the display correct.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and edited it just a bit, so this works for me :

```
CGFloat segmentWidth = 70;
CGFloat segmentHeight = 40;

UISegmentedControl *sharingSegmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"AAA", @"BBB"]];
//[sharingSegmentControl setApportionsSegmentWidthsByContent:YES];
sharingSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sharingSegmentControl.numberOfSegments * segmentWidth, segmentHeight);
for (int i = 0; i < sharingSegmentControl.numberOfSegments; i++) {
    [sharingSegmentControl setWidth:segmentWidth forSegmentAtIndex:i];
    //[sharingSegmentControl setTitle:arr[i] forSegmentAtIndex:i];
}
[sharingSegmentControl.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
[sharingSegmentControl.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[sharingSegmentControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
[sharingSegmentControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[sharingSegmentControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
[self.view addSubview:sharingSegmentControl];
```

Comment: No. Its not working for me. Check my edited question.